# Change backside color of uiview when using Curlup animation

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I have an uiview which i add a transition that removes it from an uiwindow using curlup animation. When the animation occurs the backside of the view is white...i would like to change the color of it or even put some of my own texture. Any help appreciated.

```
[UIView beginAnimations: @"Curl up" context:nil];

// wait for time before begin
[UIView setAnimationDelay:wait];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:viewToCurlUp cache:YES];
// druation of animation
[UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: +1 Creative question. Sorry for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple engineers responded that this is not possible in my case. I have asked them a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to create a texture (ie: your own image) on a UIView. The color of 'back of the curl' should correspond to the background color you have set for your UIView. You can do this in the inspector in Interface Builder, or programmatically like so:

```
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

where `view` is the UIView of interest. Use the appropriate color, of course.

Hope that helps.